# can we set adMob banner to specific <div> tag : Ionic APP

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, admob

```
`async showBanner() {
    const options: BannerAdOptions = {
      adId: ADMOB_BANNER_ID,
      adSize: BannerAdSize.FULL_BANNER,
      position: BannerAdPosition.BOTTOM_CENTER,
      margin: 5,
      isTesting: ADD_TESTING
    };

    AdMob.showBanner(options);

  }`
```

Can AdMob banners be set to display within a specific  element on a my Ionic App?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not possible.